# Could not find service with uuid error on IOS React-native BleManager

Tags: ios, react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy, iot, react-native-ble-manager

I do the same things on android it works but on IOS it doesn't work.

- I can scan devices on IOS and Android.
- I can blemanger.connect to any device on IOS and Android..
- **I can't startNotification on my device on IOS but can on android.**

I tried this:

I can connect to my device using my variable: connectedDevices.id with is in this case "E8595779-BEF2-FB78-741E-E855465F760C"

***As seen on the picture below, I connected to device using ID, But it can't find service with UUID "FFE0"
But actually there is service with UUID "FFE0"***

[image: All Info Present Here]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It finally worked,
What I learned is if you want ble manager to work on IOS, You should make fallowing changes on your working Android code,

- **Service and char UUID should be short form.**
- **You should retrieve services after you connect.**
- **You should use writewithoutresponse.**
  Much love

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem today. The answer of OP not worked for me, but I have to call retrieveServices right after connect with the peripheral.

```
await BleManager.connect(id);
await BleManager.retrieveServices(id);
```